# How do I remove “X” from search input field on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

**I have a search box on my website. Whenever the user starts to type in information, this big black "X" appears on the right side. This X only appears on the Internet Explorer. I am currently using IE 11. Could you please tell me how to remove this X from IE?**

[image: Unwanted "X" in Internet Explorer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ::-ms-clear

```
input::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```